# Rewriting <html> tag on the fly with vb

Tags: vb.net

I have over 11,000 pages in a site and need to change the  tag on every page. I interact with production through horribly slow tool so doing a global search and replace is out of the question. The site is in a .net environment and I utilize vb so I am wondering if I could rewrite the  tag sitewide on the fly with a class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's called response filtering. Please take a look at this:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx